# Jenkins/Maven build test failure

Tags: maven, jenkins

When I ran maven project from my terminal it works fine but when I ran the same test using Jenkins job it failed giving the following error :

> Error Message
>   /build-nas/jenkins/jenkins163/workspace/Gitrepo/MAVEN/TestConfig.properties
>   (No such file or directory).

I see that the file is present in the workspace and I am using Git repo where I can see the file named *TestConfig.properties*  present. Please advise. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Make sure the file is in the right place. Try this: 1. on your local machine change to your TMP directory, 2. git clone everything, 3. build everything.